# row_number over ... rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following is not compatible in spark

Tags: apache-spark, exception, apache-spark-sql, row-number

I am having a query like `row_number over partition by column name order by column name rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following`.

The query is working in the hive, but it is not working in Spark-SQL and spark (both in spark 1.6 and 2.0).

I am wondering how to implement this logic in spark code.
Is this query valid, to have rows between frame with row_number function?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/WindowSpec.html#rowsBetween(long,%20long)

Comment: Will rows between frame will work with row_number() function? I am getting an error when trying to use rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following with the row_number() function.

Answer (score 1):

- The correct syntax for window function call requires brackets around frame definition.
- `row_number` requires `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` frame and it is default in this case, so can be omitted.

Combined:

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY foo ORDER BY bar)
```